# Read specific record from DataFileReader for avro files

Tags: java, avro

My Avro files have a number of records in it, but I want to read specific records. The reader only has an interface to traverse the whole file, but I want to jump directly to specific record. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this question deserves an answer.  There is no documentation as to why this isnt possible or how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't calling [DataFileReader#seek](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileReader.html#seek-long-) be good enough? Or did I not understand your question?

EDIT: You may use the [DataFileReader#sync](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileReader.html#sync-long-) method too, so long you haven't disabled the sync markers as it is a faster alternative

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33586864)